# How can i create a searchbar like safari's searchbar ? SWIFT

Tags: swift, webkit, searchbar

How can i create a searchbar like safari

Just like the photos I posted
That the searchbar becomes small or hidden when the screen is scrolled

...

[PHOTOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQdj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could tell, what you've tried before.
That way we can help you better.

In order to do that, you need a view of type `UIScrollView` (`UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, etc.).

Implement this delegate method and it should do the trick.
Adjust the `swipeThreshold` variable to fit your needs.

```swift
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let swipeThreshold: CGFloat = 10
        let y = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y
        if y != 0 && swipeThreshold > y {
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        } else {
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

---

Old answer as reference:

Here is one way to do it — by using `SFSafariViewController` using `SafariServices`.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // Call this method when you want to show the browser
    func doSomething() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: no i dont need browser friend. i want to create a searchbar like safari app

Comment: I've updated my answer. but honestly it would be good if you could update your question to be more detailed in what you actually are looking for and what you've tried so far. Other people with a similar question can find this page that way.